# fortran 64bit ダウンロードの問題

Tags: fortran

The file is downloaded incorrectly と出てきてうまくダウンロードできません。
Version 8.1.0 
Architecture X86_64
でやってみて、他も試したけど同じように表示されました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　申し訳ありませんが、今の内容だとどこからどのファイルをダウンロードしてエラーになったのかよく分かりません。質問文を [edit] して何をしたらそのようなエラーが出たのか追記してみてください。

Comment: 版数から検索するとこれらの記事あたりでしょうか。[FortranでHello Worldまで(gfortran)](https://qiita.com/cuz/items/debe3f38f5929cecd68a), [MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)